# ADODB/C++: What does "Execute" return when single value is returned?

Tags: c++, sql, database, ado, adodb

I'm using ADO to access database..

From the documentation, _ConnectionPtr object's "Execute" method returns a Recordset
([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675023(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675023%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Likewise, the _CommandPtr object's Execute method also returns a Recordset/Stream/Nothing..
([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681559(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

However, what I don't understand is what happens if the sql command returns a single value.

For example, what happens if my sql command is as follows??

```
_ConnectionPtr myConnectionPtr;
_RecordsetPtr myRecordPtr;

myRecordPtr = myConnectionPtr -> Execute("select 1 from mydb..my_table", NULL, 1);
```

the return value of the Execute method is simply 1.. so I don't think it can be stored in the _RecordsetPtr object.. It seems like the documentation does not explain what happens if the return value is NOT a ReseultSet, but instead a value..

How do I solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will always be a result set -- the set size will just be one record if there is only one result -- but which is still a set.

Also,

```
select 1 from mydb.my_table
```

will return as many '1' as there are records in the table `my_table` -- so if there is 100 records in the table, the result set will be 100 records all with the value '1'